# Is it okay to put uncooked potatoes in a blender & then blend them up with water, & then cook them in the microwave to make potato soup?

Tags: potatoes

Is it okay to put uncooked white potatoes into a blender, and then blend them up with water, and then cook them in the microwave to make potato soup?

Comment: Define “ok” please? What exactly is your question or what are you worried about?

Comment: @Stephie Potatoes should not be consumed raw and I don't know whether this preparation method leads to sufficiently cooked through potatoes, so I would assume this is what the question is about.

Comment: You are cutting the potato en little pieces and boiling them in water. Standard cooking technique.

Comment: @CandidMoe little pieces can be tested to see if they're soft and fully cooked. If blended to a puree first, that's not possible. So if you want to ensure it's fully cooked, you'll need a new way to check

Comment: Like tasting a spoonful?

Comment: @CandidMoe no, because it's the texture you check to see if potatoes are done, and there's no texture left once it's been blended. But let's wait for the OP to clarify

Comment: Now I'm in the mood for a little cooking experiment.

Comment: ...also putting potatoes in a blender often results in a blender full of something with the consistency and property of glue. One needs to be careful blending potatoes. A food processor on low might be a better choice

Comment: My biggest concern would be that blending them  raw with a relatively small amount of water (what fits in the blender) will make a pitcher of wallpaper paste.

Comment: Raw potatoes + small amount of water + blender = pitcher of ***brown*** wallpaper paste.

Comment: I guess, it's a sort of an X-Y Problem™; why are you doing this to potatoes? What's your goal?

Comment: I'd advise to not blend it completely, leave some tiny pieces and use more water. That way it's easier to tell when it's cooked by texture and it wont become glue in your blender.

Comment: If you have a food processor, use a shredding/grating disk, and you’ll get lots of reasonably similar sized bits that will cook quickly and in a relatively uniform sort of time (so you don’t end up with uncooked chunks in an over cooked slurry)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's OK.  There may be some drawbacks to the method, such as how raw potatoes will behave in a blender and whether the results you get are what you want, but none of those make it not OK to try.  Even if you believe that raw potatoes represent a serious health risk, [which is debatable](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/raw-potatoes#intro), a microwave is more than capable of cooking potatoes.

Answer (score 0):

This recipe would definitely work, although you would want to stir the potatoes after every minute in the microwave because microwaves don't cook evenly. I would recommend adding some browned processed meat, and maybe try to put some small potato chunks in for texture. Also playing around with some fresh herbs would be interesting as well.